# Why does IE select text in the background behind my "modal dialog"?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm using a "modal dialog" where the dialog is actually a `DIV` overlayed on top of another semi-transparent `DIV` that covers the whole screen. I've reduced this down to the bare minium in [this example plunkr](https://plnkr.co/SBlEnwjIgaUpVexk17wp).

In all browsers I've tried, this works well in that the background is partially hidden, and you can't click on elements in the background - which is good.

However, in Internet Explorer (oh, yes), version 11 and possibly others, if I click in one part of the "dialog" and then shift-click in another part, it selects the appropriate content in the dialog and *also* selects text within the background content that's not part of the "dialog"(!). Like this:

[image]

This doesn't happen in Chrome. Why one earth is IE behaving like this, and is there anything I can do to prevent it?

[Note: my problem is that my "real" dialog has a pick-list inside it, which is actually an HTML table with some attached jQuery events to allow rows to be selected. I need to allow shift-selection to select a range of items, and while that all works correctly, stuff in the "background" gets highlighted too, which is very confusing.]

Comment: Can you try again after clear the browser history,cash and cookies... I Didn't saw anything like that...

Comment: @Maruf: I've tried clearing the cache and restarting the browser, and it still doesn't work. Are *you* using IE11?

Comment: Yes.. Which version of IE you got problem?

Comment: As I said in the question, IE11. Specifically 11.0.9600.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to exclusively target the background content (without targeting the modal), it may help to add a condition which disables the ability to highlight text of the background once the modal is active. Something like the following:

**CSS**

```
.noSelection {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

**jQuery Example**

```
$('.modalHandle').click(function() {

  $('.modal').hasClass('active') {
    $('.bgContentArea').addClass('noSelection');
  } else {
    $('.bgContentArea').addClass('noSelection');
  }

}
```

**Alternative**

```
$('.modalHandle').click(function() {

      $('.modal').hasClass('active') {
        $('.bgContentArea').onselectstart = function() { return false; }
      } else {
        $('.bgContentArea').onselectstart = function() { return true; }
      }

    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think that will work. If I manually add `-ms-user-select: none` to the `.data` class in my plunkr, it has no effect. (It's already not possible to select that stuff directly using the mouse *except* with a shift-click).

Comment: @GaryMcGill Please see alternative I've just posted in answer

Comment: Adding an attribute `onselectstart="return false;"` to the `TABLE` tag in my plunkr did nothing, but adding it to the `BODY` did prevent any selection, so I might be able to work with this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You won't be adding it to the content area of the modal, but the content area of the background div. Sorry if my answer was unclear. I'll edit shortly. You would possibly need to make a container div for the background content @GaryMcGill

Comment: Nope - it *only* works if I apply the `onselectstart` to the `BODY`. When I apply it to the `TABLE` (which *is* the background content btw), or even to a `DIV` I've created to contain the table, it doesn't solve the original problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, having disabled selection via the `BODY` element, allowing selection on specific child elements (such as form inputs within my "dialog") is not easy. Changing the `onselectstart` event handler for those items to return `true` does not work. I did manage to get it to work by having the `onselectstart` handler for the `BODY` look at the type of the event target, and return `true` if it happened to be an `HTMLInputElement`, which works for my particular scenario, but... *yuk*.